# Why did my dog suddenly begin this ritual of digging on her way back from a car ride?

Tags: digging, dogs

Had my dog seven years and suddenly the day after having two teeth removed she begins this ritual where every time we come back to the house from a car trip she diverts from the normal direct path to go to this one area by a bush and start digging.  She digs with her paw ~10 times and then gives up and rejoins me or (rarely) lies down.

Before this began she never dug or tried to make a bed.  She has never expressed interest in lying outside before.  She seems perfectly happy doing this, not stressed or anxious, but she is clearly strongly compelled to do it, she will try to do it 100% of the time now when we come home from a car trip.

Just curious if anyone knows how or why such behavior would become "unlocked"?